# Do not have permission to call getPageByUrl

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a new script on a Google Site that accesses a spreadsheet and displays the data to an existing List page. Similar scripts on the Site are working properly, however, in this script this particular piece of code:

```
var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/a/domain.com/page-url");
```

returns an error message: "You do not have permission to call getPageByUrl".

I am the owner of the site and target page.  Not sure what's going on here.  Can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sitesapp#getPageByUrl): you can not use a url in this format. It must be on the "canonical" sites format, e.g.:
`https://sites.google.com/a/example.com/examplesite/examplepage`

Comment: My mistake - in my script I am using the correct format, i.e.:     `code`https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.com/home. Still is not working.

Comment: Got it - sort of. I changed the double quotes (") to single quote (') and the script ran as intended.  This, however, is not really an answer or a fix - is Google trying to play funny tricks on us?

Comment: Yeah, you have probably changed something else too. Anyway, the problem was indeed on the url at least :)

Comment: Pretty sure I only changed the quotes. Also, I have two other scripts on the Site that are identical (but access a different spreadsheet).  Those use double quotes (") in the Url and run without issue. Thanks anyway for the input.